Why Scikit-learn NB model has more accuracy? | How to achieve the same score | Custom GaussianNB vs scikit-learn implementation
I have been reviewing Gaussian Naive Bayes and wondering why my custom implementation has less score than GaussianNB from scikit-learn implementation. I got result ~0.79 accuracy, while scikit model has ~0.82.
Based on my research, what effects on such accuracy difference:

Data preprocessing and handling missing values effects. (In my dataset, there is no missing values)
GaussianNB uses a smoothing parameter. They called it "epsilon". (I have inherit GaussianNB class and changed the method in such way that they do not use smoothing parameter)
Outliers might change my variance and mean.
scikit-learn uses log probability instead of ordinary probability. (My implementation also uses log probability)

How to achieve the same level of accuracy as scikit-learn implementation?

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


my_custom_model = MyCustomNaiveBayes()
my_custom_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
my_custom_model_y_hat = my_custom_model.predict(X_test)
print(f"accuracy score of my_custom model is: {accuracy_score(y_test, my_custom_model_y_hat)}")

sklearn_nb = GaussianNB()
sklearn_nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
sklearn_y_hat = sklearn_nb.predict(X_test)
print(f"accuracy score of sklearn_nb model is: {accuracy_score(y_test, sklearn_y_hat)}")

modified_sklearn_nb = ModifiedGaussianNB()

modified_sklearn_nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
modified_sklearn_nb_y_hat = sklearn_nb.predict(X_test)
print(f"accuracy score of sklearn_nb model is: {accuracy_score(y_test, modified_sklearn_nb_y_hat)}")



accuracy score of my_custom model is: 0.7980456026058632
accuracy score of sklearn_nb model is: 0.8208469055374593
accuracy score of sklearn_nb model is: 0.8208469055374593

Google Colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PkwxtJ8TCCMWl3btQiW4LN1BNuexTse2?usp=sharing
I have disabled epsilon variable, however it did not help.
I have disabled weighted mean and variance method, however, it did not give an effect.
